# Discord.js calculate winrate for 2 teams on a list of maps in a video game

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot that can calculate which of 2 teams have the best win rate on 8 different maps in CSGO.

I've tried to make a function that can calculate the win rate but I can't extract it into variables for each team. So I can display it in a discord bot. Any ideas on how I can do this?

````
const mapPool = ["de_ancient", "de_dust2", "de_inferno", "de_mirage", "de_nuke", "de_overpass", "de_train", "de_vertigo"];

//displayes absolute winrates. percentdisplay = perc1/(perc1+perc2)*100
function displayAbsoluteWinrates(){
  for(a = 0; a < mapPool.length; a++){
    perc1 = team1stats[mapPool[a]];
    perc2 = team2stats[mapPool[a]];
    percent1 = (perc1/(perc1+perc2)*100).toFixed(0);
    percent2 = (perc2/(perc1+perc2)*100).toFixed(0);

    var team1map = mapPool[a];

    //var div1 = document.getElementById("t1"+mapPool[a]);
    //div1.innerText = percent1+"%";

    //var div2 = document.getElementById("t2"+mapPool[a]);
    //div2.innerText = percent2+"%";

    if(percent2 > percent1){
      //div1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      //div2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }else{
      //div1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      //div2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    if(percent2 == percent1){
      //div1.style.backgroundColor = "darkorange";
      //div2.style.backgroundColor = "darkorange";
    }
  }
}
```

I've rewritten some code that was meant to be for an HTML site into a discord bot.

Sorry if my explanation isn't that good.
````

Comment: None of this is related to Discord.JS. Which part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work fine, here is how I tested it.

If you are needing to print the message, you need to use TextChannel#send in discord.js

https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/ if you need more assistance creating a discord.js bot.

```js
const mapPool = ["de_ancient", "de_dust2", "de_inferno", "de_mirage", "de_nuke", "de_overpass", "de_train", "de_vertigo"];
const team1stats = {
    de_ancient: 50,
    de_dust2: 50,
    de_inferno: 10,
    de_mirage: 22,
    de_nuke: 44,
    de_overpass: 22,
    de_train: 100,
    de_vertigo: 1
}

const team2stats = {
    de_ancient: 100,
    de_dust2: 25,
    de_inferno: 11,
    de_mirage: 10,
    de_nuke: 5,
    de_overpass: 2,
    de_train: 3,
    de_vertigo: 1
}

for (const map of mapPool) {
    perc1 = team1stats[map];
    perc2 = team2stats[map];
    percent1 = (perc1 / (perc1 + perc2) * 100).toFixed(0);
    percent2 = (perc2 / (perc1 + perc2) * 100).toFixed(0);

    if (percent1 > percent2) {
        // Will print if Team 1 has a BETTER WIN RATE.
        console.log(`Team 1: ${map} ${percent1}`);
    } else if (percent2 > percent1) {
        // Will print if Team 2 has a BETTER WIN RATE.
        console.log(`Team 2: ${map} ${percent2}`);
    } else {
        // Will print if the WIN RATE is the same.
        console.log(`Both Teams: ${map} ${percent1} ${percent2}`);
    }

}
```